# Exporting uesState variable into another compenent/page

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, destructuring

I'm a bit stuck. I've put the users input results into an array that can be used on another component. However when I try to destructure the 'newList' in another component/page it doesn't show anything or it returns [`Object object]` when I console.log it.

This is where the data is put into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in the `formSubmit` function - you would want to spread the input in the newList array as well, or else it would be something like

```
[[{}, {}], {},{}]
```

So, in order to have a correct list, spread the input as below:

```
 newList =[...input, ...userEnquiry]
    setUserEnquiry(newList)
```